# iPhone shows bluetooth device that doesn't exist and can't be removed

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

My wife's XR running 16.1.1 shows an item in the Bluetooth list that does not exist. It is called "S9a2cc07e548246e9C". I do not believe that is a real ID, and as we are in the forest right now, I can be certain it is not nearby. Nevertheless, we are "Connected" to this device, and unlike other devices that appear in Bluetooth Settings, there is no (i) button and no way to Forget it.

I have seen people mentioning this on the Apple support threads but there is no common solution. The most detailed one I saw suggested toggling Airplane Mode for 10 seconds and then doing a restart, so I did that and it immediately came back, so no fix.

Any suggestions?

Comment: IIRC, if this is the _only_ Bluetooth device in the list, it might not be able to be removed until another Bluetooth device is added to, and connected to, Bluetooth. You should then be able to remove the errant device.

Comment: No, it continues to appear even when we went back to the car and the stereo appeared in the list. We also tried at home where there were a couple of entries and its still there and unable to be removed.